# Can we upload app on play store without changing minifyEnabled false

Tags: android, google-play-services, apk

if yes then why minify enabled it give so much crash in apk.
Thank you

Comment: check [this](https://youtu.be/x9T5EYE-QWQ?t=592)

Answer (score 0):

If the app is crashing after setting minifyEnabled to true then you must check for proguard rules. Some classes must be kept as it is. After setting proguard rules only upload that apk to play console.